# Why does addClass work on one element but not another?

Tags: jquery, haml

The class, "open", gets added to the `ul` element, but not the `dropdown#register` element.

```
<ul class="nav"></ul>
<script> $("#register_dropdown").addClass("open"); </script>
<script> $("ul").addClass("open"); </script>
<span class="dropdown" id="register_dropdown"></span>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with the ID `#register_dropdown`? It's not `dropdown#register`

Comment: Yes, see the last line of code.

Comment: Maybe move your script call to below where you're creating the `#register_dropdown`? A bit of the rendered HTML would be more useful than HAML as well.

Comment: If it's `haml`, please label it `haml`.

Comment: If you ever end up with `$("ul").addClass("open");`, you've got a problem (see the global `ul` selector?).

Comment: That's easily fixed with a more specific selector `$('ul.nav')` or giving it an ID if needs be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#register_dropdown")` returns an empty jQuery object as `register_dropdown` is not present in the DOM when you execute that line.

I'm not experienced with HAML, but wrapping your scripts inside the [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is the way to go:

```
%script $(function(){ $("#register_dropdown").addClass("open"); });
```

In plain markup it should be rendered as:

```
<script> $(function(){ $("#register_dropdown").addClass("open"); }); </script>
```

You can also use the more verbose way if you prefer (same result as the one above):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //DOM is ready, put your code here
    $("#register_dropdown").addClass("open");
});
```

This prevents your code from running until the DOM has fully loaded. You may as well just move that line after the element is added to the DOM, but it's good practice to manipulate the DOM after it's ready.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)